How do I use Discord OAUTH2 to find a Discord role of the user logged in?
I'm looking to gate the administrator panel of a website I made for a Discord bot behind the administrator role. Basically, the user can log in right now but they can ALSO see the admin panel without actually being an administrator of the Discord.
I need to know how you would go about handling this using flask or discord.py and Discord OAUTH2.

You need to have the guild and guild.members.read scopes in your discord OAuth url, then when a user authenticates, you will have a token which grants you access to the API on their behalf, you can then fetch the users roles at any time, using that token with a GET request to the /users/@me/guilds/{guild.id}/member API endpoint, this will return the users information in that guild, including roles, then you can filter it to look for a specific role in that guild. You can find detailed information surrounding the discord API in their dev docs.
Alternatively, if the dashboard is being run in the same process as the bot, you can interact with the bot to verify their roles, doing this may make some people more comfortable on authorizing with your dashboard as they know you cant access their member information for all guilds, this also applies if it is on the same computer as you can run a HTTP server alongside the bot to interact with the it.
